# Spring-RabbitMQ : Any Converter for sending Spring`s Multipart file

Tags: spring-rabbit

I want to publish MultipartFile to the queue and bind the rabbit listener to retrieve the MultipartFile from the queue.

I tried sending as bytes and able to retrieve it. Is there any converter available to support multipart conversion?

Please provide the suggestions.

Comment: Do you have any other solution yet?